# Is there any way to List all the files present in a folder using Javascript without using any HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, file, protractor

I am trying to automate an Angular application using Protractor and I came across a scenario where I need to list all the files present inside a folder.

I know in Java we can use the following:

```
File f = new File('D:\Practice');
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));
```

But i couldnt get a solution in Javascript.

Comment: This is going to depend on your JS environment. For example, this is going to be close to impossible from a browser. It is usually not considered a good thing if a web page can enumerate files on your computer.

Comment: You're gonna need a back-end tech in order to access files. In Node.js, you would use `fs.readdir("path", function(err, files) { ... })`

Comment: You can access FS from protractor script but not from the browser.

Comment: You should be more specific and provide more details on the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js File System `readdirSync`
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/tmp'); // returns list of filename as an array
```